# Regular expression not working completely in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, comments

So, I am trying to apply regular expression to email addresses coming into a site I am working on to try and verify that they are mostly valid. The regular expression is the one below.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])
```

When put into ruby as below.

```
if email =~ [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@ (?:[a-z0-9]
(?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])
#logic here if regex passes
end
```

The problem is that the regular expression below contains '#' characters which are understood as comments in ruby. So, is there a way to use the regular expression without the '#' being interpreted as comments? Can regular expression be stored as strings or something similar?

Comment: Your pattern must be enclosed between delimiters: `=~ /[a-z0-9!.....[a-z0-9])/` (don't forget to escape slashes inside the pattern)

Comment: If you want to be sure that the entire string match your pattern (and not only a part), you must add anchors for the begining `\A` and the end of the string `\z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use ruby regex syntax `/regex/`, or build new regexp with `Regexp.new(string)`

```
regexp = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])/

if email =~ regexp
  #logic here if regex passes
end
```

Comment: Please escape the 2 forward slashes hidden in that clustered expression (or use `Regexp.new()` like you said).

Comment: @Sam - Thanks, I missed them completely. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I wasn't aware that delimiters had to be used. Many thanks for the quick response!